# Programatically fill the screen with buttons

Tags: android, button, layout

I'm trying to add buttons programmatically to the layout so that they position themselves automatically next to the existing one, or on a new row if they don't fit.

I'm not sure if I'm explained properly, so will put an example of the result that I'm trying to achieve:

Phone screen:

```
|[button1][button2][button3]|
|[sort][LongButton][sort]   |
|[tooLongSoGoesNextRow]...  |
```

So far I've managed to automatically put them together in the same row, but can't make them "jump" to the next row if they don't fit anymore on the current one. I came from HTML and I thought it would be pretty easy to do, but either I'm doing it the wrong way, of it isn't...

This is how my layout currently looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code I'm using to add the buttons:

```
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonsLayout);

   //set the properties for button
   Button btnTag = new Button(getApplicationContext());
   btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   btnTag.setText("WHATEVER");
   btnTag.setId(generator.nextInt());

   //add button to the layout
   layout.addView(btnTag);
```

This will add buttons on the same row, without overlapping each other, but they would just keep being added next to each other, even if they are not fitting on the screen.

Comment: did u try setting width for linear layout as match_parent and height as wrap_content ?

Comment: Edited the post to show the current layout xml that I'm using. Haven't tried with match_parent on the width, will do and revert. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, I solved it with a custom ViewGroup (following this http://hzqtc.github.io/2013/12/android-custom-layout-flowlayout.html):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FlowLayout extends ViewGroup {

    private int paddingHorizontal;
    private int paddingVertical;

    public FlowLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paddingHorizontal = 0;
        paddingVertical = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int childTop = getPaddingTop();
        int lineHeight = 0;
        // 100 is a dummy number, widthMeasureSpec should always be EXACTLY for FlowLayout
        int myWidth = resolveSize(100, widthMeasureSpec);
        int wantedHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                continue;
            }
            // let the child measure itself
            child.measure(
                    getChildMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec, 0, child.getLayoutParams().width),
                    getChildMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, 0, child.getLayoutParams().height));
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            // lineheight is the height of current line, should be the height of the heightest view
            lineHeight = Math.max(childHeight, lineHeight);
            if (childWidth + childLeft + getPaddingRight() > myWidth) {
                // wrap this line
                childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
                childTop += paddingVertical + lineHeight;
                lineHeight = childHeight;
            }
            childLeft += childWidth + paddingHorizontal;
        }
        wantedHeight += childTop + lineHeight + getPaddingBottom();
        setMeasuredDimension(myWidth, resolveSize(wantedHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int childTop = getPaddingTop();
        int lineHeight = 0;
        int myWidth = right - left;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                continue;
            }
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            lineHeight = Math.max(childHeight, lineHeight);
            if (childWidth + childLeft + getPaddingRight() > myWidth) {
                childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
                childTop += paddingVertical + lineHeight;
                lineHeight = childHeight;
            }
            child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);
            childLeft += childWidth + paddingHorizontal;
        }
    }
}
```

In the layout:

```
    <my.package.app.FlowLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonsContainer"/>
```

And adding the buttons programatically:

```
            ViewGroup flowContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.buttonsContainer);
            Button btnTag = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            btnTag.setText("whatever");
            btnTag.setId(23425);
            flowContainer.addView(btnTag);
```

I hope it helps somebody. Now I'm just struggling to add a vertical scrollbar :).

Best regards,
Javier